# JVM / Spring boot response times

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jvm

I'm currently rewriting a Ruby on Rails web app in Spring Boot. A big part of the move is for performance.

Whilst developing the app, when I hit run in IntelliJ the first response time is typically around 1s which I assume is JVM startup, after a refresh it'll jump down to 300ms~ then 150ms for 4-5 further requests, after that it settles on 50-75ms for the most part. Randomly though later on I'll get a 150ms response again.

As a JVM novice I'm wondering what factors are at play here in the varying response times? which would be closer to the standard "hot" response times that I could expect in production? I realise I'm unlikely to get an accurate depiction of production performance on my local dev machine but would like to understand the variance seen above so I can at least gauge a little better what affect my incremental changes are having.

Comment: This is being run in intelliJ on your local worskstation and you are worried about a 150ms response time?  Consider that intellij is using a heapload of memory and is performing tons of tasks, GC etc.

Comment: @ScaryWombat not worried at all, all of the above response times are several factors faster than the app they're replacing and well within acceptable territory. Just wanting to understand a little better what's going on with the variations seen.

Comment: Sure, what other tasks are happening on your workstation? Linux or Windows? GC? swap? other system io?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm running OSX. The "warm up" pattern from 150ms to 50-75ms seems consistent though each time I run the app regardless of whatever else I may be doing. I'm guessing that's normal, if so, does it then "cool down" again after a few minutes without requests? that would certainly explain what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a JVM novice I'm wondering what factors are at play here in the varying response times?

startup:

- jit warmup
- lazy initialization as part of your application
- GC needing to settle on some heap size

steady state:

- GC pauses
- application behavior, e.g. cache entries expiring every now and then
- varying load
- JIT deoptimizations/recompilations due to some uncommon paths being taken
- thermal CPU throttling, especially on but not exclusive to laptops

For server applications you should ignore the ramp-up behavior and focus on steady state. And guessing what the issue might be will not help, measurements are king.

Comment: "JIT deoptimizations/recompilations due to some uncommon paths being taken" - all useful insights but that bit in particular is most interesting. I'll need to read more on it. What range of requests should I be warming up the app with to get a stable/optimised JVM environment?

Comment: As i said, measurements are king. So chart the response-time and see how long it takes to settle.